# How to use redis server in Amazon Ec2 correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I have installed the Redis server on the Amazon EC2 instance.
Redis is working fine on the server
Now I want to open the port 6379 for it "Edit inbound rules" in the security group
can you please tell me Type and protocol for it I should use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

- Type: Custom TCP Rule
- Protocol: TCP
- Port range: 6379
- Source: *depends on your needs*

Also consider [**AWS ElastiCache**](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) - managed Redis service.